# How to access files in a server directory from client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the easiest way to access files located in node.js directory from client side?
My project structure goes like this:

```
+Project
++client
++files
++other backend stuff
```

Do I have to make a routing for GET so the client can get the file via HTTP or is there some other option like directly getting files from a folder?

Comment: You can't access to information like files or databases from client side(javascript), it would be too dangerous.

Comment: @Bélgica I found answer to my question, you can just serve files in a static way using express, it works fine

Comment: Express its node js, its server side my friend. Maybe i didn´t understand you.